# A fresh Win10 installation doesn't see neither printer nor NAS, whereas original one does

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, nas, network-printer

My laptop (ZBook 15 G4) came with one drive with Win10 (let's call it Installation A) on it. I installed another SSD and put a fresh Win10 on it (installation B). I was planning to format the original drive to put Linux on it, but didn't get to it yet. So right now I have two drives, both with separate Win10 Pro 1803 on them. Pretty identical, one would think.

The problem: Installation A sees the NAS on my router (FritzBOX 5490) and the wireless printer (without installing any drivers first). Installation B doesn't see any of those plus I cannot access my router's interface, neither by typing its IP address nor by using the "address" fritz.box. Both methods work on installation A and on other devices.

What I tried: followed a few guides that did what worked for them in similar cases, like installing "Support for SMB 1.0/CIFS" and activated several services. If it's relevant, I will edit the exact names in.

What I suspect: maybe I missed a driver? What other difference is there between an OS installed by HP/vendor to a "self-installed?" That used the newest WiFi drivers from Intel's site rather the ones from the model-specific collection?

Any other ideas?

**EDIT** The FritzBOX uses SMB 1.0 according to [the manufacturer](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-5490/knowledge-base/publication/show/3327_SMB-versions-supported-by-the-FRITZ-Box/)

**EDIT2** Well, the issue was only resolved by re-installing, using a diffrent .iso. Makes it look like it was a bad .iso, somehow

Comment: What version of SMB does your NAS use?  Edit your question

Answer (score 1):

The generic Windows 10 drivers apparently don't work with some of your hardware.

Download and install the missing drivers from the
[HP Support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-15-g4-mobile-workstation/14840009).

If this doesn't solve the problem, you will need to backup the drivers from
the version that works and import them to the other.

For driver tools, see
[Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Comment: Installing the WiFi driver from HPs site didn't change anything, sadly

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the network profile setting that is set on your "installation B".
Check the profile which is active (most likely "Public").
Change it to "Private" and make sure your "Private Network Profile" has "Network Discovery and Sharing" enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately this is already the case. Those setting were "correct" by default